# How to unsuspend code analysis in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, code-analysis

I've got `Code analysis is suspended` icon at the upper right corner of editor window

[image]

As probable result of this, PyCharm does not see any errors and dosn't syntax highlight.

How to unsuspend it?

Comment: Is there anything that comes up as a warning or error in the PyCharm `Event Log` at the bottom right?

Answer (score 3):

Try doing `Code | Inspect Code...` and running it manually on the file (or potentially at all)

I've not personally run into this, but this is mentioned as a solution to this issue [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206897215-Code-analysis-has-been-suspended)